# Visibility of Menu Buttons

Tags: android, menu

I am struggling to meet the specs of a homework project on the visibility of menu buttons.  The project states that there should be three visibility buttons:  all, x, and y.  Cliking on x and clicking on y should each causes 2 menu items to be visible or invisible.  Clicking on all should cause all 4 items to be visible or not.  When all 4 items are not visible, the 3 visibility buttons should be visible.

My problem is I have not been able to figure out a way to have the 3 visibility buttons visible when all 4 menu items are invisible.  I tried various ordering and groupings in groups.xml to no avail.  It should be pretty simple but for some odd reason I am not able to figure it out.  I also cannot find any resource to learn from (not using the right words to search?).  Please give me a few pointers!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Activity` (or `Fragment`), where you get reference to your buttons I would do something like the following where the visibility buttons will be named `x`, `y` and `all` and the four buttons they control will be `button1`, `button2`, `button3`, and `button4`.

We need a method that can tell us, if all four buttons are invisbile. For this we need to use the method [`isShown()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isShown%28%29) which returns true if a `Views` visibility is set to `VISIBLE`:

```
private boolean areButtonsInvisible() {
   return !button1.isShown() && !button2.isShown() && !button3.isShown() && !button4.isShown();
}
```

This method will return `true` if and only if all the buttons have their visibility set to `GONE` or `INVISIBLE`.

Then we need a method for handling the visibility of the three view state buttons:

```
private void handleViewButtons() {
   if( areButtonsInvisible() ) {
      x.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
      y.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
      all.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
   }

   //You can handle other situations here as well. I haven't added any because you haven't stated anything about other scenarios.
}
```

Then in the `OnClickListeners` of `x`, `y` and `all` you just add a call to the method `handleViewButtons()` after you have set the visibility of `button1`, `button2`, `button3`, and `button4`.